# Adding external config file to application.properties

Tags: java, application.properties

I have a configuration file in the resources folder that I wanna add the path to in the application.properties folder. But the following code is not working.

**application.properties**

```
appconfig=config.cfg
```

Because of the nature of my application, I require an external *.cfg* file. Is there a way I can add the file to application.properties?

Comment: Where do you have `appconfig=config.cfg`? What code are you using to read your properties file? Why can't you just give that the path of an external file?

Comment: @tgdavies I have it in the application.properties file. I tried giving the path of that directly in the java code, but I keep getting a file not found error.